# C# MVC5 - Table com CheckBox e Ações Diferentes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou trabalhando em um projeto do qual eu possuo uma página que lista alguns registros, dos quais eu irei 'flegar' alguns para realizar ações em lote, como exclusão, alteração de status, entre outros.

Como faço para enviar essa minha lista com os registros 'flegados' para diferentes actions?

Minha lista é construída assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Selecione</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int r = 0; r < Model.Count(); r++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i[r].Selecionado)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => i[r].Descricao)</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>

<input type="button" value="Alterar Selecionados Para Status x" />
<input type="button" value="Alterar Selecionados Para Status y" />
<input type="button" value="Alterar Selecionados Para Status z" />
}
```

No meu método post, eu recebo o parâmetro da seguinte forma:

```
[...]
public ActionResult SelectLines(List<Objeto> list) { [...] }
```

Comment: Através de Ajax. Você já conseguiu gerar essa lista para que eu possa direcionar isso como código?

Comment: Sim, tenho uma action 'Index' do qual possui uma lista de objetos com um campo booleano chamado 'selecionado'. Se eu faço um único submit, eu consigo passar esta lista para minha action pelo método POST sem nenhum problema. Porém em casos de mais de uma ação, eu não sei como fazer... Como eu enviaria a lista através de ajax para uma action específica? via: **data: $('table').serialize()** ?

Comment: Então, o clique do campo dispararia o Ajax. Pode colocar na sua pergunta um exemplo em código?

Comment: O grande desafio seria o Ajax saber pra onde enviar a informação. Como é uma *Action* diferente por linha, teria que ter uma maneira de anotar a informação que levasse para a *Action* em algum lugar do HTML.

Comment: Se você quer atuar *a mesma ação* em cada coisa que está selcionado, fica bem mais simples. Assim consegue clicar em tantas checkbox que quer, e clicar Submit apenas uma vez. Eu usaria o mesmo Model que você usou para gerar a lista no seu View. Apartir daí é só transformar os ítens selecionandos em um JSON array

Comment: Putz... Confesso que fiquei meio confuso... Editei a minha pergunta, para tentar detalhar mais a minha dificuldade. Eu consigo normalmente enviar a lista para uma action presente em um form. Nesta action eu varro a lista em busca dos itens 'selecionados' para ai começar a tratá-los.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A solução mais elegante que conheço](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111222/1314276) é implementar um atributo de detecção de botão de *submit* de `form`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultipleButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var isValidName = false;
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Argument);
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
            controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = Argument;
            isValidName = true;
        }

        return isValidName;
    }
}
```

Altere seus botões para:

```
<input type="submit" value="Alterar Selecionados Para Status x" name="status:x" />
<input type="submit" value="Alterar Selecionados Para Status y" name="status:y"/>
<input type="submit" value="Alterar Selecionados Para Status z" name="status:z"/>
```

O *Controller* ficaria assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "status", Argument = "x")]
public ActionResult MudarParaStatusX(MeuViewModel mvm) { ... }

[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "status", Argument = "y")]
public ActionResult MudarParaStatusY(MeuViewModel mvm) { ... }

[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "status", Argument = "z")]
public ActionResult MudarParaStatusZ(MeuViewModel mvm) { ... }
```

Comment: Show!!! Muito bom! Só fiquei com uma dúvida: aonde devo implementar essa classe MultipleButtonAttribute?

Comment: Crie um diretório chamado `Attributes` na solução e implemente lá. O *namespace* deve ficar `MeuProjeto.Attributes`.

Comment: Entendi! Resolveu o problema! Inclusive, consegui resolver com o uso do Ajax, passando o atributo 'data' da seguinte forma: ´$('form').serialize()´; Resolveu também, porém não sei se é uma boa prática, até porque foi bem simples de implementar... Mas gostei bastante da sua solução! Obrigado!

Comment: @AntônioFilho Essa com o serialize é a abordagem Ajax que eu tinha comentado, mas sou propenso a usar requisições tradicionais para o servidor por uma questão de estilo. Fique à vontade para usar qualquer uma das duas soluções.

Comment: Implementei hoje essa solução, porém ele não redireciona corretamente para a action. A expressão: `if (value != null)` retorna null sempre... E estou fazendo exatamente como descrevesse...

Comment: Estudei este conceito de Attributes e encontrei alguns exemplos mais simples, considerando o attr name da tag como o mesmo nome da action. Porém no método override da classe Attributes, ele não localize meu form submit...

Comment: [Pode entrar aqui, por favor?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc)

Comment: Como te falei, havia um detalhe errado na resposta, que era o `type` do `input`, que não é `button`, e sim `submit`. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Já estou usando o type="submit"